# Vuetify, how to change color on error state in input

Tags: validation, vue.js, input, vuetify.js

```
<v-text-field
    placeholder="Enter the name of the city"
    append-icon="search"
    autofocus
    clearable
    color="secondary lighten-4"
    :rules="inputRules"
  ></v-text-field>


data() {
return {
  inputRules: [
    v => v.length >= 3 || "Type at least 3 characters"
  ]
};
```

}

Above I paste example input in Vuetify. My question is how to style Input by in the state when inputRules === false change from red by default to any other.
I am asking for the simplest way possible. Is there an option not to do it with very specific css selectors or flag!Important?

Thank you very much for all the tips

Answer (score 3):

```
<v-text-field
    placeholder="Enter the name of the city"
    append-icon="search"
    autofocus
    clearable
    color="secondary lighten-4"
    :rules="inputRules"
    class="form-input"
></v-text-field>


<style>
.form-input >>> .v-input__slot::after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;
}

.form-input >>> .v-input__slot::before {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;
}
.form-input >>> .error--text {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;
}
.form-input >>> input {
  caret-color: white !important;
}
</style>
```